# Как компилировать windows form с++?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

У меня есть Form.h и к ней программный код(все работает правильно), так как я совсем новичок в visual с++, я понятия не имею как теперь мне это дело компилировать, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: создать пустой проект и добавить туда эти два (два?) файла. Вот только это не совсем С++. Это C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас не Visual Studio Express 2012, то есть такое решение, попробуйте:
http://www.t-hart.org/vs2012/

Comment: нет, у меня полная версия, пробная